# require js with underscore.js not working

Tags: requirejs

I am following the tutorial at:

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/07/requirejs-amd-tutorial-introduction

I am basically making a simple template module that requires "jquery" and "underscore"

Here is my app.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min",
    "underscore": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.3/underscore-min"
  }
});

require(['template'], function(template) {

    //Template is undefined
    console.log(template);
});
```

Here is my template.js

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery'], function() 
{
  var showName = function(n) 
  {
    var temp = _.template("Hello <%= name %>");
    $("body").html(temp({name: n}));
  };

  return 
  {
    showName: showName
  };  
});
```

I have verifed that all the scripts are pulling in via google chrome's network tab, but the template callback is NOT defined.

EDIT: 
It seems the error is caused by return with `{` on another line. I have never run into this before with javascript...Is there a rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It seems the error is caused by return with { on another line. I have never run into this before with javascript...Is there a rule for this?

Answer (score -1):

Despite best efforts of certain luminaries to convince gullible newcomers otherwise, [semicolons are optional in JavaScript](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/). This has some implication to how return keyword is handled. See the link.

One of the issues with people thinking that semicolons are required is - they think that the parser will continue parsing until it encounters a semi... Gotcha!